# Is it possible to download an old version app from Mac App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore

I recently updated Numbers/Keynote on my mac2 (10.14) to 6.2/9.2, and rsynced to mac1 (10.13). Then I found they do not run on 10.13.

I deleted them on mac1 and tried to re-download. It told me to upgrade macOS instead of letting me download last working version for 10.13.

So is it possible to download an old version app from Mac App Store?

Comment: Do you have a Time Machine backup or an rsync backup from mac1?

Comment: I have a TM backup, with /Applications excluded...